# Как выполнить свой код... (wordpress, woocomerce)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать так, чтобы после обновления статуса заказа на "обработка", выполнялся мой код? Как вообще можно отловить изменение статуса? Это вообще возможно сделать без редактирования плагина?

P.s. я искал ответ в goog, я пытался найти ответ в документации api (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#libraries-and-tools), но в ней я нашел лишь возможность получения данных о заказах.

Comment: Хмм... Вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090181/woocommerce-order-status-changed-hook-getting-old-and-new-status пример чтения документации и гуглежа если я правильно понимаю вопрос то вам нужен следующий хук `add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','callback');` когда меняется статус

Comment: Вот что я нашёл в документации http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#create-a-webhook все хуки

Comment: @Walfter спасибо что ответили, сейчас посмотрю :)

Comment: @Walfter как говорится, ответы - в ответы! Ответ правильный, и он может оказаться полезным для тех, кто ищет решение подобной проблемы.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я не был уверен что это ответ и только попытался натолкнуть автора. Так как я не работал с woocommerce, и говорил только из общих познаний WP, и думаю, если он решил эту задачу то автору и надо было дать ответ к своему вопросу

Comment: @Walfter Я еще не читал то, что вы скинули. Как только вернусь к своей проблеме я почитаю то что вы скинули и отпишусь, то ли я искал или нет. Но в любом случае спасибо за активность :)

Comment: @Walfter, ваш ответ действительно мне помог. Напишите ответ в ответы и я отмечу его как правильный. Так же я наткнулся на данную тему, думаю ее тоже необходимо вставить в ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315825/woocommerce-order-status-completed-not-triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя WP хуки:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','callback', 10, 3); // 10 приоритет хука 3 количество отдаваемых параметров
function callback($order_id,$old_status,$new_status) {
    if ($new_status == 'processing') {
        // какой то код
    }
}
```

[Пример на английском стаке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090181/woocommerce-order-status-changed-hook-getting-old-and-new-status)

[Второй пример на английском стаке от автора вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315825/woocommerce-order-status-completed-not-triggered)

[Хуки в плагине WooCommerce(документация)](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#create-a-webhook)